# Get remote MKV file metadata using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ffmpeg, mkv

I need to extract the softsubs embeded into an mkv file hosted on a remote server using nodejs.

All of the solutions I've found online so far are using local files, and others are either poorly documented or throwing unknown errors that I can't find online; That doesn't work for me. I need to extract subtitles from the remote file (like `http://some-url.com/videos/video.mkv`) without downloading the entire file to use it in my web-based application.